# "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\getID3' not found" when trying to include a PHP file in Laravel 5

Tags: php, class, laravel, classnotfound

I'm using **getid3** library with a Laravel project.
I created a folder called "includes" in the app/ directory and inside it a folder called **getid3** which contains a bunch of php files, I included the getid3.php file which resides in that directory.
Here is the file content along with the library on **Github**:-
https://github.com/JamesHeinrich/getID3/blob/master/getid3/getid3.php

In the controller, when I try to instantiate the getID3 class which is defined in that file, I get following error:-

```
FatalErrorException in ApiV1.php line 217:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\getID3' not found
```

Here is the code block in the controller in which I'm trying to instantiate the class

```
ob_start();
if ($fp_output = fopen($FilenameOut, 'wb')) {

    ob_end_clean();
    // Initialize getID3 engine
    $getID3 = new  \getID3;
    foreach ($FilenamesIn as $nextinputfilename) {

        $CurrentFileInfo = $getID3->analyze($nextinputfilename);
        if ($CurrentFileInfo['fileformat'] == 'mp3') {
```

How to solve this error ?

Comment: Where is line 107 in you code block?

Comment: Obviously the line where the getID3 class is being initialized :).

$getID3 = new  \getID3;

Comment: @Jerodev Sorry, the line 107 is that line

\App::make('url')->to("/audiofiles/$enAudioTitle.mp3");

When I added the backslash, the problem was solved.
The backslash also solved the main error.
Marked as correct answer.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class has been defined in the root namespace, you need to add a `\` before the class name. Otherwise php will think it is in the same namespace as the current class, currently `App\Http\Controllers`.

You should do something like this:

```
$id3 = new \getID3;
```

Comment: When I added that backslash, The error became:


    FatalErrorException in ApiV1.php line 107:
    Class 'App\Http\Controllers\App' not found

Comment: Can you show the code from that line? If you are calling `App`, you also need to add a backslash before it. `\App`

Comment: ...................
 ob_start();
    if ($fp_output = fopen($FilenameOut, 'wb')) {

        ob_end_clean();
        // Initialize getID3 engine
        $getID3 = new  \getID3;
       ...... foreach ($FilenamesIn as $nextinputfilename) {

            $CurrentFileInfo = $getID3->analyze($nextinputfilename);
            if ($CurrentFileInfo['fileformat'] == 'mp3') { ......
.....................

Comment: Can you add the code from `ApiV1.php` in your question, because this is very hard to read. Or create another github blob.

Comment: Done.
Btw, the problem was solved on its own, then I cleared the cache of the Laravel project, the problem returned again.

Why do you think this happened ?